# Multiple queries vs. huge WHERE IN

Tags: sql, vba, db2

I have to select a bunch of rows from a database (DB2), based on an array of ID's. However as the amount of rows can become rather large (up to 7,000), the multi-row query (below) will fall to the 30 seconds time-out in VBA. I am instead considering a looped single-row approach, but I have no clue how much stress this will put on the database.

Is the looped single-row query a reckless approach? And are there any better solutions, without writing to the database?

Multi-row:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_table.id IN ('0001', '0002', '0003', ...)
```

Single-row:

```
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;
WHILE @cnt < cnt_total
   SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_table.id = @cnt
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END;
```

Comment: Store those values in a separate table, do a JOIN.

Comment: @jarlh it is a solution that I have considered, by then I would have to apply writing into a database I would prefer to only read from. However, the idea is not bad, and should be considered for others who might encounter the same issues as I did.

Comment: Note - pretty much all dbs have bulk-load utilities, made for loading millions of rows.  If you consistently have a large number of ids, it may be worth it to try using that to load the temp table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

7000 calls will be very slow, because of the number of round-trips.

The best approach to solving this problem is creating a temporary table, populating it with 7000 rows, and joining to it in your query.

If this approach is not acceptable, you could limit the number of round-trips by querying, say, a 1000 rows at a time in a loop. This would give you seven round-trips instead of 7000, which should be a lot faster.

Comment: So basically, if I used the multi-row query seven times, it would be a better approach? Because that would be doable...

Comment: @Noceo Yes, using a multi-row query seven times is a lot better than using a single-row query 7000 times. In fact, I know a commercial product that did just that to work around Oracle's limit of 1024 elements in an 'in' list.

Answer (score 2):

The looped single-row query is more reckless.  Well, at least it doesn't perform as well.

In general, executing a query incurs overhead.  At the very minimum, the databases engine needs to parse the query, determine the query plan (which may be passed), execute the query, and return the results.  Repeating this steps requires extra effort.

From a performance perspective, the `IN` is a better approach.

That said, it might be easier to process the code row-by-row at the application layer.  And if you only have a handful of values, the performance difference might not be very important.  But, the better approach is a single query.

Answer (score 1):

Use a BETWEEN query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
  WHERE my_table.id BETWEEN '0001' AND '7000';
```

Given the code you've shown for the single-row query it appears that the ID values are consecutive, with known starting and ending values. Given this, one query which returns all the rows you're looking for is a better idea.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I might have oversimplified my example a bit. My ID values arent nessesarily an interval like that. However there is a chance they might be somewhat consecutive, so I will look into it.